Error: Cannot find module 'D:\NEXTJS\sample-next-micro\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\lib\ModuleNotFoundError'
when npm run dev, i get this error
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\NEXTJS\sample-next-micro\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\lib\ModuleNotFoundError'
how to fix it?
my package.json
...
"dependencies": {
    "@module-federation/nextjs-mf": "^8.6.3",
    "next": "^14.2.13",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "webpack": "^5.95.0"
  },
...

my next.config.js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-require-imports
const NextFederationPlugin = require("@module-federation/nextjs-mf");

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, options) {
    if (!options.isServer) {
      config.plugins.push(
        new NextFederationPlugin({
          name: "home",
          remotes: {},
          filename: "static/chunks/remoteEntry.js",
          exposes: {
            "./home": "./src/pages/index.tsx",
          },
          shared: {},
          extraOptions: {},
        })
      );
    }

    return config;
  },
};

expected : no error and success compiling
